# Liquibase : Expected something between the "TABLE" keyword and the "IF" keyword

Tags: teradata, liquibase

I am trying to run the below sql by liquibase and I am getting an error expected something between "TABLE" and the keyword "IF" keyword .This is for teradata database

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME, NO, FALLBACK,
NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
NO AFTER JOURNAL,
CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO AS ( I TRIED WITHOUT "AS")
(
COL1 INTEGER,
COL1 INTEGER....ETC)
PRIMARY INDEX( COL1,COL2);
```

Comment: Well, CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS is not valid Teradata syntax.

Comment: Could you please help me with the syntax. Appreciate your help in advance

Comment: `CREATE MULTISET TABLE SCHEMA_NAME.TABLE_NAME(
COL1 INTEGER,...`

Comment: But I would like to check if the table already exists before creating it.

Comment: You'll get an error message if the name is already in use. If it's a script (e.g. run in BTEQ) you can simply ignore the *table already exists* error. But if it exists it might have a different definition and you have to check the DDL anyway.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since etl is dropping and recreating in the process I took advantage of that and I followed the same pattern like drop and create. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE <database_name>.drop_if_exists( in_object varchar(50)) begin IF EXISTS(
SELECT  1 
FROM    dbc.tables 
WHERE   tablename = in_object 
    and databasename='<database_name>') THEN 
CALL DBC.SysExecSQL('DROP TABLE ' || in_object); 
END IF; END;
```

Followed by the regular create table statment.